# Suggestion: Upon bounty submission, provide message to those who have previously posted an answer

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I answered up a question to somebody a few weeks ago.  The person didn't like my answer, but never commented a single word that they didn't like that response.  Instead, they waited for a few weeks, then posted up a bounty.

I sure would like to know that.  I had no idea the person wasn't satisfied with my answer. Is it possible to submit a message to anyone who provided a previous answer, that a bounty has been submitted?

Yes, I realize there is a check mark for accepted answers... but hey, lots of folks fail to check an approved answer.. so that's not 100% either.

ref: [original Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051807/how-to-work-with-2-xmlhttprequest-one-dependent-on-another)

Comment: Alternatively, when the bounty notice says "One of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.", you're essentially being notified that your answer is awesome.

Comment: Ha, not in this case.  Frankly,  I was more miffed at the downvotes from the bounty hunters.  But I will say, offering up a bounty says pretty strongly you want another review AND you are not satisfied with the current responses.  At least let me know that (and in this case, the failure of the original questioner to comment at ALL was disappointing...)

Comment: You are miffed at the downvotes - but if there were no downvotes you probably would not have become aware of the bounty - so maybe there is a certain value to that, although perhaps in a twisted sort of way.

Comment: Actually, nah, one of the guys who downvoted me, also left a comment. It was that comment that I initially responded to.  Had it not been for that comment, I'd still be in the dark as any issue on that question at all.  Hence my request here on SO-meta.

Comment: Also note that in general when somebody asks how to do a certain thing or has a specific problem in a language dumping code without any explanation which uses some external library isn't a great answer. Bounty or no bounty. Because OP does not only have one problem he had two because of that answer.